# Freezing/Burning in Vacuum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

When a rabbit is brought out of space craft where the outside temperature are $773K$;
(A) The rabbit gets burnt to death
(B) The rabbit gets frozen to death
(C) The rabbit gets burnt and frozen simultaneously
(D) Cannot say

The answer given is (B). Can someone explain ?

Answer (score 3):

The key is in the interpretation of temperature in space. The value of 773 K means that the molecules of gas in space are moving quite quickly; however, their density is very very low. The total energy transferred to an object immersed in gas is proportional to the product of gas density and gas temperature (i.e. number of particles and energy per particle). Though the temperature is higher than Earth's by a factor of 3 or so, the density is lower by a factor of several hundred, if not more; therefore, outer space isn't really heating the rabbit at all.

The rabbit, being born and raised on Earth, in a dense atmosphere, has a metabolism tuned specifically to equalize heat transfer. Therefore, it radiates roughly the same amount of heat that it would receive from the atmosphere under normal conditions. In space, it still radiates the same amount, but it receives essentially no heat from the dilute conditions. Therefore, there is a net outflow of heat from the rabbit, which will result in its freezing to death.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @probably_someone; but what about the water, shouldn't the water from the rabbit's skin evaporate or something like that.

Comment: Evaporation speeds up the cooling process, as it's endothermic.